# Creating graph with tables

Tags: c#, charts

```
for (int t = 0; t < ARF.Rows.Count; t += 1)
{
    Chart1.Series[t].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
    Chart1.Series[t].BorderWidth = 2;

    Chart1.Series[t].ToolTip = "(#VALX,#VALY)";
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1" + t.ToString()].AxisX.Title = "Learning Domains";
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1" + t.ToString()].AxisY.Title = "Covered";


    Chart1.Legends.Add("Legend1" + t.ToString());
    Chart1.Legends["Legend1" + t.ToString()].Enabled = false;
    // Chart1.Legends["Legend1" + t.ToString()].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
    Chart1.Legends["Legend1" + t.ToString()].Alignment = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;
    Chart1.Legends["Legend1" + t.ToString()].DockedToChartArea = "ChartArea1" + t.ToString();
    // Chart1.Legends["Legend1" + t.ToString()].IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;
    Random random = new Random();
    foreach (var item in Graph.Series[0].Points)
    {
        System.Drawing.Color c = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255));
        item.Color = c;

    }

    Chart1.Series[t]["PointWidth"] = "0.2";
    Chart1.Series[t]["BarLabelStyle"] = "Center";
    Chart1.Series[t]["PixelPointDepth"] = "99";
    Chart1.Series[t]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";

}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv.DataSource = ds;
    ph.Controls.Add(gv);
}
```

This is code to creating  5 charts, i want 5 charts with 5 tables of Grid View data together in 1 shot. can you please help me to do...i have tried but graphs are coming and grids are not visible.

Comment: Give us a fighting chance what is Chart1?

Comment: I meant the .NET type

Comment: ya..simple .net chart using data visualization property

Comment: `<asp:chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">`, right?

Comment: ya i want something like this   [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hOhEA.jpg dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using web application you can use google chart:
You can refer this link:

```
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls
```